# (iOS) In firebase Analytics "kFIRParameterItems" parameter not accept array and its returns an error "InvalidArrayParamEventName (21)"

Tags: ios, swift5

```
//Array not accept in Firebase Analytics on "kFIRParameterItems" parameters
var arrCompleteItems = [Any]() // create array to set on "kFIRParameterItems"

        for obj in headerItems{
            
            if let items = ServicesContainerViewModel.cartData[obj.id] as? [String: Any] {
                if let data = items[InputKeys.items] as? [Item_list] {
                    
                    for obj in data{
                        let itemDetails: [String: Any] = [
                            AnalyticsParameterItemID: obj.id ?? "",
                            AnalyticsParameterItemName: obj.name ?? "",
                            AnalyticsParameterItemCategory: obj.parentCategoryName ?? "",
                            AnalyticsParameterQuantity : obj.itemQuantity ?? ""
                        ]
                        arrCompleteItems.append(itemDetails)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
        let itemDetails: [String: Any] = [
            AnalyticsParameterCurrency: "INR",
            AnalyticsParameterValue: "",
            AnalyticsParameterItems: arrCompleteItems ,
            "user_name": Person.sharedInstance.firstName,
            "email": Person.sharedInstance.email,
            "mobile_number": Person.sharedInstance.mobileNumber
        ]
        
        Analytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalyticsHelper.isTesting+AnalyticsEventViewCart, parameters: parameters)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this issue with default event name,

Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventViewCart, parameters: parameters)

I noticed that you are unable to see ITEMS parameter in the Firebase console. Upon checking, there is an internal bug filed on Firebase end. It’s expected that it will not show yet in the Firebase Console (DebugView, dashboard, etc.). However, this parameter can be seen in BigQuery, but it’s only supported for the Retail/Ecommerce events.